# Return entries with common columns values in pandas DataFrame - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in python pandas which contains several different entries (rows) having also integer values in columns, for example:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
0  1  2  1  0  1  2  1  2  
1  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  2
2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  3
3  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  2 
4  2  2  1  2  1  2  1  3
```

I would return just the rows which contain common values in columns, the result should be:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  
1  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  2
3  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use the boolean mask from [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) passing param `keep=False`:

```
In [3]:
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]

Out[3]:
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  2
3  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  2
```

Here is the mask showing the rows that are duplicates, passing `keep=False` returns all duplicate rows, by default it would return the first duplicate row:

```
In [4]:
df.duplicated(keep=False)

Out[4]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Need [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with parameter `keep=False` for return all duplicates with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.duplicated(keep=False))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

df = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  2
3  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  2
```

Also if need remove first or last duplicates rows use:

```
df1 = df[df.duplicated()]
#same as 'first', default parameter, so an be omit
#df1 = df[df.duplicated(keep='first')]
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
3  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  2

df2 = df[df.duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df2)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  2
```